# Compilier says he did it, but he didn't

Tags: firebase, android-studio, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I have this code:

```
val currentEmail = firebaseAuth.currentUser?.email.toString()
    var pass = false
    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    db.collection("users").get().addOnCompleteListener{
        if(it.isSuccessful){
            for(document in it.result!!){
                if(document.data.getValue("email") == currentEmail && document.data.getValue("name") != null){
                    Log.d("TAG", "asd")
                    pass = true
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(pass){
        binding.nameRegister.visibility = View.GONE
        binding.ageRegister.visibility = View.GONE
        binding.buttonRegister.visibility = View.GONE
        binding.profileName.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        binding.mapBtn.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        recreate()
    }
```

And when i start the app, it shows "asd" in Logcat, but even though it means that "pass" is now "true", the code after "if" doesn't work. Please ask if you need me to send something else

Comment: `if(pass)` most probably happens before `pass = true`. Note the latter is inside the listener.

Comment: Yeah.  put `Log.d("TAG", "qwe")` just before the `if(pass){` so you can see which happens first.

Comment: There is no way you can use the value of  `pass` outside the listener. Firebase API is asynchronous. So please check the duplicate to see how can you solve this using a callback. You might also be interested in reading this article, [How to read data from Cloud Firestore using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953).

Comment: Thanks, people! You all helped a lot!